# React Websockets not working with Laravel Echo Server

Tags: reactjs, laravel, websocket, laravel-echo

I've currently got websockets working with my project with a React front end ([www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com)) and a Laravel back end (api.mysite.com) with Laravel Echo Server. It is noted that my front end and back end are two separate IPs. It appears that everything is working properly, but for some reason I'm not seeing a `console.log` whenever an event fires.

Here's my laravel-echo-server setup:

```json
{
    "authHost": "https://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {},
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        }
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": false,
        "allowOrigin": "",
        "allowMethods": "",
        "allowHeaders": ""
    }
}
```

And I am seeing the event being logged here:

```
L A R A V E L  E C H O  S E R V E R

version 1.6.2

⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

Channel: chat.9332
Event: LeagueChatCreated
```

Here's how I have everything set up on the front end:

```js
import Echo from "laravel-echo/dist/echo";
import socketio from "socket.io-client";

const echo = new Echo({
    host: "https://api.mysite.com/socket.io",
    broadcaster: "socket.io",
    client: socketio,
});

export default echo;
```

```js
useEffect(() => {
    echo.channel("chat." + leagueId).listen("LeagueChatCreated", (ev) => {
        console.log("new request");
    });
}, []);
```

And if this helps at all, I'm seeing the sockets logged in the network tab
ex: https://api.mysite.com/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=Nv0ZpN4
Here's the response back from that:

```
96:0{"sid":"zboOkFWvkLvOj8xKAADx","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":5000}2:40
```